# insert images in place of text

Tags: php, jquery, image, button

I'd like to replace "prev" and "next" with images (previous.png and next.png) in the below code, I'm just not sure of the proper syntax. Any ideas?

```
if ($arrOptions['_slider_controls']){
            $output .= '<div class="thethe-image-slider-controls-prev thethe-previous thethe-image-slider-controls" id="thethe_image_slider'.$oPost->ID.'-previous"></div>
                    <div class="thethe-image-slider-controls-pause thethe-image-slider-controls thethe-';
            $output .=$arrOptions['_slider_autoplay'] ? 'pause' : 'play';
            $output .='" id="thethe_image_slider'.$oPost->ID.'-pause"></div>
                    <div class="thethe-image-slider-controls-next thethe-image-slider-controls thethe-next" id="thethe_image_slider'.$oPost->ID.'-next"></div>';
        }
```

If it matters, I'm using [TheTHe Image Slider](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/thethe-image-slider/) for Wordpress.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to replace but try replacing prev with `<img src="previous.png">` and next with `<img src="next.png">`

Comment: @IonutHulub I replaced `-next` with `<img src="next.png">`, the button I was trying to change was removed, but my replacement button isn't showing up. I also tried `<img src="images/next.png">`, same results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you want to do. The image slider is most likely inserting the Prev and Next controls on the fly. They might not even be text, they might already be an image. If you have a link to a working demo it would be easier to see but I would do the following:

1. Determine if Prev and Next are being displayed as text or if they are an image. Use something like Chrome developer tools to see the page's structure and you can figure that out. The reason it might already be an image is so they could use a specific font without headaches.
2. If they are an image, find the source of the image. If it's in the css of the plugin you can change it there. If it's an image file being inserted into the html you can overwrite it with your own, just give it the same name.
3. If it's really just text then you can look through the slider plugin files and find the place where it's inserted. CTRL+F for "prev" or "next" might help speed this up. Carefully change that instance to insert your image instead.

Be warned that if you edit the slider plugin files then your changes will probably go away if you ever update the plugin to a newer version so saving notes about the changes you made will be helpful in the future.

Edit:
None of the ones in your demo used the words prev/next, but they did use a background image: http://thethefly.com/wp-content/plugins/thethe-image-slider/style/skins/frame-black/buttons.png 
If you find the corresponding file in your install you should be able to overwrite it with your own. But even better, it looks like that plugin is skinnable. I didn't see any information on how, but look through the files and see if there are any skin/theme/config files that you can edit. Also look for editable stuff in the CSS files that came with it if there are any.

Edit again: I just read your comment again and I realize yours might be different. Do you have access to any of their themes? Modifying one of theirs might be easier if it uses images by default. Also to tell for sure using chrome browser right click on it and choose "inspect element" and you can see exactly what's going on. Other browsers have similar functionality if you use something else.

Comment: Here is a live demo- http://thethefly.com/2201/blog/news/thethe-image-slider-live-demo/

My initial thought that the buttons were images, but while looking through the images folder, I saw nothing. My best guess, is the white background is indeed an image, but the "Prev" and "Next" on the buttons is text. Ideally, I'd like to swap it all out for my own images without "Prev" and "Next" text.

Comment: Yep, I've checked all the CSS and didn't really find anything relating to these buttons in a specific way. Perhaps my comment to @Ionuthublub above will explain better.

Comment: Removing `-next` and `-previous` resulted in the total removal of those element, if that helps. Where can I look to find where those elements are defined?

Comment: In the demo the background image style is inserted inline so you would not see it in the CSS. So I guess it wouldn't be configurable from there then.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, there is no way at all, whatsoever for me to change it?

Comment: Yeah, don't mess with your PHP output. the -next and -prev you changed are just part of that div's id. Changing those broke that div, that's why it disappeared.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17319/discussion-between-syntax-error-and-amc)